# Android - Picasso image orientation changed

Tags: android, android-imageview, picasso

In my android application, we are using Picasso plugin to display the file in to the imageview. Please refer the below code.

```
 val pf= File(photo!!.thumbnailPath)
                Picasso.get()
                        .load(pf)
                        .into(imageView)
```

I am using latest Picasso plugin and in this code, if we select landscape image from gallery then the image will display fine on the ImageView. But if we select the portrait images then it will automatically change the orientation while displaying it on ImageView.

I knew this is the known bug in Picasso plugin and I tried lot of other possibilities and couldn't able to fix it. Can anybody have any idea about how to display all images in proper way in the ImageView without any orientation.

[image]

In above diagram car image as landscape and flower image as portrait mode. I need to fix that flower image (portrait mode) should display properly as it is in gallery.

Thanks
AK

Comment: There is no code that selects an image. We have no idea what you do.

Comment: @blackapps : which means always it will change the orientation when we select the portrait images from gallery ?

Comment: Repeat: `There is no code that selects an image. We have no idea what you do. `